# Process Builder - Flow - Run After Record Is (Actually) Saved (Committed)

Tags: process-builder, administration, visual-workflow, order-of-execution, hack

**Is there a way using a Flow (Process Builder directly, if possible) to do something on a record AFTER it is COMMITTED?**

*To be clear:*   literally at the end of the **standard Order Of Execution** (doesn't have to be "before" the "post-commit logic").

I'm trying to circumvent issues with managed packages (mainly Rootstock) where when an Account is created (and the RS Customer checkbox is true), it creates a RS Customer record **at the same time**, and I cannot interact (such as pushing the ID of the RS Customer record to the Account) due to Order Of Execution and Rootstock's (hidden) Apex, using Workflows or Process Builder.

I can't help but think a Flow might do the trick, but I've not figured it out yet.

- START
- When NEW record 'objA' is inserted
- - NEW record 'objB' is inserted
- - 'objB' has LOOKUP to 'objA'
- WAIT for record 'objA' (and 'objB'??) to COMMIT
- Copy a value from 'objB' record to 'objA'
- END

The Process Builder to copy a value from 'objB' record to 'objA' record works fine normally - *"child, write a value to parent record"*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54705/discussion-on-question-by-amm-process-builder-flow-run-after-record-is-actu).

Answer (score 1):

Create a time-based flow in Process Builder that runs "one hour before Created Date".  This causes the step to be queued immediately, and it should fire very quickly (brief tests show 1-2 minutes in a Sandbox).

[image]

---

**Original Answer**:   What you can do is build a Process build or workflow with a time-based workflow of -1 hour of create.  This will wait till all jobs are executed and add this process to the queue for the first available time to execute.

Comment: Interesting.   -1 hour?   Really?   I guess I will have to try this.  Thanks.

Comment: "-1 hours" as a scheduled action (from Created Date or "from now") = "Invalid value" unfortunately

Comment: In a vaguely similar Question, someone suggested a Formula DateTime field that equals "Date - 60 min".... that may work in this scenario.....  playing with that now.

Comment: Fascinating.   It "worked".  It took about 2 minutes to come in.  I'm going to make the Formula-Date 90 minutes back and see if that improves speed.  I do realize it's in a queue, but this is Sandbox and very little is happening.   I ALSO notice there is a "before" timer option, so I may be able to just use Created Date "Before" 1 hour ago...

Comment: Seemed to take about a minute, using 1 Hour BEFORE Created Date.    It's so close... I may use this until something better comes along.  I could make any processed on Account "wait" for the field I'm populating to ACTUALLY POPULATE, I suppose (best would be that the field IS POPULATED at time of creation, but beggers/choosers, etc....).  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Glad to see that it may work for you! Cheers.